# I need to display selected checkbox items , if user click previous button able to show the selected items

Tags: flow-screen-component

I developed one screen flow where the user selects multiple items through LWC I implemented. Clicking Next will redirect me to next screen. When I click on Previous button I am unable to show the selected checkbox items.

this is my JS code.

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunityProducts from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityListOfProductsController.getOpportunityProducts';
import createSolutionSaleLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityListOfProductsController.createSolutionSaleLineItems';
import { FlowNavigationNextEvent,FlowNavigationBackEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';
//import { FlowNavigationBackEvent,} from 'lightning/flowSupport';
const COLS = [
    { label: 'Products', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { label: 'ListPrice', fieldName: 'ListPrice', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'Notes', fieldName: 'Notes', type: 'text', editable: true},
];
export default class OpportunityProductsTable extends LightningElement {
    @api solutionSaleId;
    @api opportunityId;
    @track oppData = [];
    columns = COLS;
    isOtherSelected = false;
    selectedOpp = [];
    isProductSelected = false;
    proQuantity;
    ProNotes;
    connectedCallback() {
        getOpportunityProducts({ oppId: this.opportunityId })
            .then(result => {
                if (result !== null) {
                    this.oppData = JSON.parse(result);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
    handleRowSelection(event) {
        let selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        let selectLineNumbers = [];
        let otherSelected = false;
        if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
            this.isProductSelected = true;
            selectedRows.forEach(row => {
                if (row.Name == 'Others') {
                    otherSelected = true;
                    selectLineNumbers = [...selectLineNumbers, { name: row.Name, product: row.Product, quantity: this.proQuantity, notes: this.ProNotes }];
                } else {
                    selectLineNumbers = [...selectLineNumbers, { name: row.Name, product: row.Product, quantity: row.Quantity, notes: row.Notes }];
                }
            });
            this.selectedOpp = selectLineNumbers;

        } else {
            this.isProductSelected = false;
        }
        this.isOtherSelected = otherSelected;
    }
    handleQuantityInputChange(event) {
        this.proQuantity = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedOpp.forEach(row => {
            if (row.name == 'Others') {
                row.quantity = event.detail.value;
            }
        })
    }
    
    handleNotesInputChange(event) {
        this.ProNotes = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedOpp.forEach(row => {
            if (row.name == 'Others') {
                row.notes = event.detail.value;
            }
        })
    }
    handleBack() {
      
            const navigateBackEvent = new FlowNavigationBackEvent();
            this.dispatchEvent(navigateBackEvent);
            
    
    
}
    handleNext() {
        createSolutionSaleLineItems({ serializedOppRequest: JSON.stringify(this.selectedOpp), solSaleRecId: this.solutionSaleId })
            .then(result => {
                this.error = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
        const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, *Complete* and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to store the selected checkboxes from LWC in a flow variable and use it inside Connected callback to re-store the selected checkboxes. Here is a simple example on how to do it. First you have to expose the selected checkboxes to Flow. To expose attributes from the LWC, you first use `@api` in the LWC’s javascript, as is standard for any property you want to make accessible outside of the component. Then you additionally specify the public property by adding inside `targetConfig` section. Then create a Flow variable and assign the LWC property to this.

*HTML*

```
<template>
    <lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group" label="Checkbox Group" options={options} value={value}
        onchange={handleChange}></lightning-checkbox-group>
    <p>Selected Values are: {selectedValues}</p>
</template>
```

*JS*

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class CheckBoxGroup extends LightningElement {
    @api selectedValuesFlow = "";
    value = ['option1'];

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Ross', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'Rachel', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }

    get selectedValues() {
        return this.value.join(',');
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.value = e.detail.value;
        this.selectedValuesFlow = this.selectedValues;
    }
    //set existing selected value by user 
    connectedCallback(){
        this.value = this.selectedValuesFlow.split(',');
    }
}
```

*XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="selectedValuesFlow" type="String" label="Selected Checkboxes"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

*Flow Variable*

[image]

*Assign the Flow Variable to LWC*

[image]